Azure Devops - Set Specific Visual Studio (2022) Version?
Microsoft has been breaking our Azure C++ and .NET builds lately with the constant stream of Visual Studio 2022 updates into the Azure Pipeline agents. For example, at the time of writing, they've broken something in C++/CLI within Visual Studio 17.12.2 and we are getting tired of being the beta testers - however my question isn't about this specifically...
Can we not set the exact version of visual studio being used in DevOps to prevent it from always taking the bleeding edge versions?  I cannot seem to find anyway to set this.  Preferrable, I'd like to be able to set my build pipelines to use one of the LTSC versions of Visual Studio instead such as 17.10.X, etc. We are building from the agents hosted within DevOps not on-prem (and would prefer to keep it this way).
Thanks!
I have tried setting the version via MSBUILD flags which did not work.  I've also tried setting various C++ toolset versions; however they don't appear to be installed on the DevOps agents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml If you meant Microsoft hosted agents tagged as windows-latest, then you don't have any control on VS2022 version. Self hosted agents are the option you need to go.
